# How do the A320 flight controls reconfiguration laws work?

Tags: flight-controls, airbus-a320, fly-by-wire

Can someone explain in simple terms the reconfiguration laws? I have hard time understanding ELAC, SEC, FAC Priorities in FCTL Architecture Diagram.